# Selecting a string/number with MySQL query in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to achieve the following MySQL query in Zend Framework 1.11:

```
SELECT [other_columns], 1 AS dontShow FROM deal_merchants;
```

I am interested in selecting the number 1 and giving it the `dontShow` alias. However when I run the following code:

```
$select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITHOUT_FROM_PART);
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->from('deal_merchants',array('MIN(BidPrice) AS price','USERS_ID','MIN(BidQuotaFrom) AS MinFrom','MAX(BidQuotaTo) AS MaxTo','users.ImageURL','1 AS dontShow'));
```

I get the following exception:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'deal_merchants.1' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it. Not sure if it's the best way, but it works. Here is how, if someone stumbles over this:

```
$select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITHOUT_FROM_PART);
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->from('deal_merchants',array('MIN(BidPrice) AS price','USERS_ID','MIN(BidQuotaFrom) AS MinFrom','MAX(BidQuotaTo) AS MaxTo','users.ImageURL','(SELECT 1 FROM dual) AS dontShow'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put column/alias as key/value in array i.e:

```
array('price' => 'MIN(BidPrice)', ...)
```

Key is an alias, value is a queried value.